# Vaadin table row listener triggers multitple times on click

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Hello i am working in a custom listener for click events in a table row in vaadin 7.
The problem is that the trigger jumps one time for every row there is on the table.
Is that the normal behaviour?

My code:

adding listener to the table

```
table.addItemClickListener(new MyCustomListener());
```

listener code:

```
public class MyCustomListener implements ItemClickListener  {

@Override
public void itemClick(ItemClickEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String id = event.getItem().toString();

  System.out.println(id);//If the table has X rows this is printed X 
                         //times even if i click a single time in a row

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a minimum example with Vaadin in version 7.7.16 where I created a table, filled it with 3 entities and added your MyCustomListener. Whenever I click on a row, there is only fired one event only for the selected row. So no, this is not the normal behaviour. Are you sure that you only call addItemClickListener once on your table? You should check, that this method is only called once. Maybe you want to put a break point at

```
table.addItemClickListener(new MyCustomListener());
```

because if addItemClickListener is called multiple times, there will be multiple ActionListeners which are all executed (as the method name says it **adds** a listener). And it seems like you are adding as many new Listeners as the count of entities you have in your table.

Comment: That was the problem!!!! , i was adding several listeners to the table. Thanks!!!!!!